# ajax call (to send file) to call c# function not working(webmethod)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

This form i want to send using ajax call with file, but it is not calling the c# function and not showing any error.

```
//form to submit
<form id="formfile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body">
       <input type="file" id="fileupload1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" id="savefiles" class="buttonType" onclick="saveFile();return false" value="Save File" /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

This ajax call is used to call c# code and also send file(.pdf)

```
//ajax call in .aspx file
function saveFile() {
    debugger;
    var file = $('input[type="file"]').val();
    var exts = ['pdf', 'PDF'];

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("imageFile", $('#fileupload1')[0].files[0]);

    if (file) {

        var extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, file.length);

        if ($.inArray(extension, exts) > -1)
        {
            //var formData = new FormData($('#form1')[0]);
            var fileUpload = $('#fileupload1').get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;  


            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }
            formData.append(fileUpload.name, fileUpload);
            //alert('File Uploaded Successfully!');
        }

        else
        {
            alert('Invalid file, Only pdf files can be uploaded!!!');
        }
    }
    //var str = "abc";
    $.ajax({
        url: "FileUploader.aspx/savepdfFiles",
        type: "POST",
        //cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;

        },
        error: function (data) {
            debugger
        }
    });
}
```

It will come into success section also, but not calling following method.

```
//c# code
[webMethod]
public static void savepdfFiles()
{ 
   //code
}
```

In ajax call it goes into success. but not calling savepdfFiles() method.

Comment: have a look, what function name you written to call <input type="submit" id="savefiles" class="buttonType" 
          onclick="SaveFileToTemp();return false" value="Save File" />
and what is your function name.

Comment: sorry, actually I was trying the code that's why, but on submit it will call that method.

Comment: The main problem is that it is not calling C# method.

Comment: Can you call any other C# method? the server could be sending a response that is interpreted as success, but not allowing the method to execute... check your app configuration on your server.

Comment: yep, I am calling the same method with no data or string data, it's working fine. But for PDF(or file), there is some problem.

Comment: When you call it with a string you put the content type to JSON right ?

Comment: yes, at that time it will be JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this problem and it's easy to solve just you have to use Generic Handler.
Using generic handler with your AJAX call you can send any file to asp.net C# function.
In Generic Handler you have to write following c# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace UploadFile
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for UploadFileHandler
/// </summary>
public class UploadFileHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        //context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                string fname;
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                {
                    string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                    fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    fname = file.FileName;
                }
                fname = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fname);
                file.SaveAs(fname);
            }
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("File Uploaded Successfully!");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the example...

**If you want Full Example** Click [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwit_vTKvPfOAhUItI8KHZ4RCpo4ChAWCBowAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lateshtclick.com%2Fblogpost%2Fuploading-files-using-jquery-ajax-and-generic-handler-ashx-in-aspnet&usg=AFQjCNGKX2DhkkAE5XgUeVQy7trnPwLMHw&sig2=ifJuzZdjtpFdAFSpmwRrRw)!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 24/08/2016**

You can convert your blob data to base 64 and send it in JSON

```
var filesLength = 0;
function SaveFileToTemp() {

    var file = $('input[type="file"]').val();
    var exts = ['pdf', 'PDF'];

    var pdfList = [];
    // var pdfFile = { FileName: '', B64Data: '' };

    if (file) {

        var extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, file.length);

        if ($.inArray(extension, exts) > -1) {

            var fileUpload = $('#fileupload1').get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;

            filesLength = files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var reader = new window.FileReader();
                reader.myFileIndex = i;
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    base64data = reader.result;
                    pdfList.push({ FileName: files[this.myFileIndex].name, B64Data: base64data.substr(base64data.indexOf(',') + 1) });
                    console.log(base64data);
                    filesLength--;
                    if (filesLength === 0) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/FileUploader.aspx/savepdfFiles",
                            type: "POST",
                            //cache: false,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ listPdf: pdfList }),
                            success: function (data) {
                                //alert('File Uploaded Successfully!');
                                debugger;
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                debugger
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
            }
        }

        else {
            alert('Invalid file, Only pdf files can be uploaded!!!');
        }
    }          


}
```

and in C#

```
[WebMethod]
public static void savepdfFiles(List<PdfFile> listPdf)
{
    //code
    foreach (var item in listPdf)
    {
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(item.B64Data);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("d:\\temp\\{0}",item.FileName), data) ;
    }

}
```

this is my clas PdfFile for info

```
public class PdfFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string B64Data { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe you have to add this to your web.config to allow big json serialization :

```
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="10240000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

You have to set the appropiate value for maxJsonLength

**Previous answer**

I think I had this problem before from what i remember there is mechanism that doesn't allow you to this.

Maybe I'm wrong but I share you a [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks).
You will have to handle this with an ashx.

> here is a built-in validation layer of protection that ASP.NET
>   enforces for both GET and POST based ASP.NET AJAX web methods, which
>   is that regardless of the HTTP verb being used, ASP.NET always
>   requires that the HTTP Content-Type header is set to the value
>   application/json. It this content type header is not sent, ASP.NET
>   AJAX will reject the request on the server.

Comment: Yes, using .ashx it is working fine, but we want it in same page only.

Comment: So if I'm right you can't use content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, or multipart/form-data